# Place values on google graph

Tags: php, javascript, google-api, google-visualization

How can i place values on the 'google.visualization' graph  ?

please see image attached.

[image: graph example]

```
var options = {
      width: 1024, height: 240,
      title: 'Clicks from Welcome email',
      vAxis: {title: 'email Clicks',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}}
    };
```

this is the solution

data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'annotation'});

in the google graph its all about layers, so i added this layer,
watch out that the type is the same type as in your rowData

> var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
>           data.addColumn('string', 'date');
>           data.addColumn('number', 'Remove');
>           data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'annotation'}); // annotation role col.
>           data.addColumn('number', 'Add');
>           data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'annotation'}); // annotation role col.
>           data.addRows([]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of functionality was recently introduced to gviz using DataTable roles: you can use extra columns of information in your datatable to create annotations and other types of functionality.

See the first example here for a guide to what I think you want:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/roles.html#whatrolesavailable

Comment: Thank you very much, i add the line

data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'annotation'});

in the google graph its all about layers, so i added this layer,
watch out that the type is the same type as in your rowData

Answer (score -1):

You will have to set your data when calling the Chart API, like this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
data.addRows([
  ['2004', 1000, 400],
  ['2005', 1170, 460],
  ['2006',  860, 580],
  ['2007', 1030, 540]
]);
```

Then set your options with your code above and draw the chart:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

It's all explained in the extensive [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html)

Comment: hi, yes i made this, the graph is working,
but
i want to add toltip with values on every graph row as describe in the picture